# Write a check constraint on columns from two tables

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, constraints, check-constraints

I have this simple database I'm working on as assignment in university:
I don't need full solution, I just need the way it work.

[image]

1: UsageCount : how many times they used the question in past exams.

2: CorrectAnswerCount : how many student Answered the question right.

3: StudentCount : The number of student took the exam.

My question is:

How do I make a check constraint (between QuestionInExam and Exam) enforcing that `CorrectAnswerCount <= StudentCount`?

Also, how do I raise the UsageCount for a question every time it is used in an exam?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Weird, your question doesn't really sound like a question to me.

Comment: I'm using SQL server 2008 ... 
the question is how to make a check constraint  between to tables ... I tried to do it but it didn't work ...

Comment: I would remove the relationship between Question and Course. You have a loop there. You can easily relate Question to Course through the Exam table.

Comment: they give us the diagram like this in university :\

Comment: For the second part of your question, I would recommend using a AFTER INSERT trigger to add 1 to the UsageCount after a record is inserted to QuestionInExam https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396